# How to prevent offset in subcaption / subfigure

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

I have the following problem trying to align two figures horizontally within the same figure environment. The right image is always put lower than the left image. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure} 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{plots/dipfdbs_componentSizeComponentCount.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{plots/dipfdbs_averageDegree.pdf}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Degree distribution and component sizes of dipfdbs recommendation graph.}
    \label{fig:dipfdbsgraphplots}
\end{figure}
```

And here is how it looks like in rendered pdf:

[image: result]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

The optional argument to the `subfigure` environment defines the vertical alignment of the image within the subfigure, so `b` will place the images at the bottom of the subfigure, `c` centers them and `t` places them on top. You've used `b` on the first and `a` in the second, but `a` doesn't do anything as far as I know. Change `a` to `b` to fix it.

(Images are from the [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Degree distribution and component sizes of dipfdbs recommendation graph.}
  \label{fig:dipfdbsgraphplots}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently the OP thought `a` and `b` would appear in subcaptions.

Comment: @lhf That could explain it.

Comment: Thanx a lot... a and b had been set due to a previous usage of an old package for getting the subcaptions. Saved my day!