# Align top of images using subcaption

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I'm trying to align the tops of two images using the subfigure environment from the subcaption package. Unless I'm misinterpreting the other questions, I believe I have read multiple questions asking the same, [Align by the top borders of figures when using subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56289/align-by-the-top-borders-of-figures-when-using-subcaption) and [How to prevent offset in subcaption / subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/how-to-prevent-offset-in-subcaption-subfigure) are two examples. The problem is, those answers don't seem to work as I expected, and I still can't get the tops of the images to be aligned.

example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=20em]{example-image-a}
            \caption{taller image}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=15em]{example-image-b}
            \caption{shorter image}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{two images}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For me this generates the following:
[image: Result Image]

I would have expected it to align the tops of the images. How do I do this?

Comment: Add `\vskip 0pt` at the very beginning of each `subfigure` environment.

Comment: @Jubobs that did it. Why is that necessary to get what I assume to be the expected behavior of the [t] option?

Comment: The `subfigure` environment is based on the `minipage` environment, so the following question and answers are relevant to your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top

Comment: This seems a bug of the `subcaption` package - Submmit to @axel-sommerfeldt

Comment: Put `\caption{...}` before of `\includegraphics{...}` but caption appears above of figures. I didn't find an easy solution

Comment: Effectively add `\vspace{0pt}` after of `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}` in both `subfigure`s, and ready!!!. I don't know why, but works!

Comment: Reopened from "Duplicate of" state on OPs request. While the linked duplicate technically solves the issue, I agree with the OP that an answer should address `subfigure` directly, as beginners don't see the connection to `minipage` directly.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/27/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that `[t]` aligns to the *first baseline* (`[b]` to the last baseline) of the included paragraph, not the top of the content. The baseline of images lies on there lower edge, so `[t]` has basically no effect with two images. Lower the images to include the baseline on top or add an empty line above them (using e.g. `\vskip 0pt`) to make it work.

Further information on this problem can be found in [Understanding minipages - aligning at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34166/understanding-minipages-aligning-at-top). Note that `subfigure` uses a `minipage` (or the equivialent?) internally.

Comment: Nowadays I would recommend the `adjustbox` package for this. With it the images can be align with multiple different ways: adding `valign=T` for both images for example or adding `raise=5em` in this case to the second image.

Comment: `adjustbox` works for me, while `vskip` doesn't.

Answer (score 11):

### Newer solution

For anyone who come across this issue with subcaption package >= v1.2, there is a **built-in** argument for that:

> `\begin{subcaptionblock}[⟨outer-pos⟩][⟨height⟩][⟨inner-pos⟩]{⟨width⟩}`
> ...
> Beside the `⟨outer-pos⟩` values of ‘c’, ‘t’, and ‘b’, the subcaption package also offers the values ‘T’ and ‘B’ additionally which align the subfigure at the very top resp. bottom. (In contrast ‘t’ and ‘b’ align the subfigure at the top resp. bottom baseline.)

Basically `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}` aligns the top of the two caption text boxes. So not effective as both of your subcaption texts are of the same height. `\begin{subfigure}[T]{0.45\textwidth}` aligns the very top of the two outer box (the entirety within `subcaption`), which suits your need.

Comment: @Matt please consider making this solution the accepted answer. :) Simple and yet solves exactly the problem!